# Sloping/inclined header

Tags: html, css

Can't understand how to make [this trick](https://www.freepik.com/free-psd/modern-corporate-flyer-template_1252890.htm#term=web) or [this](https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/artboard_hero_banner.jpg) with css. I mean the header and the flag. The line is not straight. They are inclined/sloping bordered. 
Could you, please, give an example or just exmplain this works?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/josedvq/3HG6d/

**HTML**

```
<div class="triangle-up-left"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.triangle-up-left {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle-up-left:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: -500px;
    border-bottom: 500px solid transparent;
    border-left: 500px solid #4679BD;
}
```

They use a trick where you make some borders transparent in order to create a triangle. More information about this technique at [How do CSS triangles work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work)

Comment: So easy. Thanks a lot!